# Bouncy Castle & the 'New' ISignatureFactory

Tags: certificate, bouncycastle

*I include 'New' in scare quotes because I'm unsure of when the interface was implemented (and the old `SetSignatureAlgorithm()` method deprecated).*

I'm following this code:

https://github.com/rlipscombe/bouncy-castle-csharp/blob/master/CreateCertificate/Program.cs

As it was written some eight years ago, it uses the now-deprecated [`SetSignatureAlgorithm()`](https://github.com/rlipscombe/bouncy-castle-csharp/blob/9fa62299af96361ab973affab23b461abbe8770c/CreateCertificate/Program.cs#L189) method. But I'm running into a problem when using the new `ISignatureFactory` API:

```
ISignatureFactory signatureFactory = new Asn1SignatureFactory(PkcsObjectIdentifiers.Sha256WithRsaEncryption.ToString(), subjectKeyPair.Private, random);
var certificate = certificateGenerator.Generate(signatureFactory);
```

When I use this new syntax, a new certificate signed by a previously-created Root CA comes out corrupted:

[image]

Oddly, the Root CA itself is created just fine. It's only the child certificate that fails. And when I switch back to the deprecated syntax, everything sails through just fine.

How can I use the new `ISignatureFactory` syntax to successfully sign a child certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, got it. I was using the wrong private key:

```
ISignatureFactory signatureFactory = new Asn1SignatureFactory(PkcsObjectIdentifiers.Sha256WithRsaEncryption.ToString(), subjectKeyPair.Private, random);
```

I was signing the new certificate with its own private key. That's why it was working for the Root CA but not the child.

I changed `subjectKeyPair` to `issuerKeyPair` and everything worked as expected.